# Alquém pode me dizer o que há de errado neste código?

Tags: c

Estou criando uma função que recebe e quebra uma string em várias, dependendo do(s) delimitador(es) escolhido pelo programador. Então tenho:

```
void split(const wchar_t* text, const wchar_t* seps,wchar_t ***str, int *count)
```

- text: a string a ser quebrada
- seps: os delimitadores
- str: vetor de strings (retorno)
- count: número de strings quebradas

A função parece funcionar sem nenhum problema e nenhum *memory leak*.
O problema é que quando uso a função a saída do texto (na janela do X11), aparece com cores aleatórias. Já apaguei todo o corpo da função, mas o problema ainda assim persiste.

O código está assim:

```
void split(const wchar_t* text, const wchar_t* seps,wchar_t ***str, int *count){
    //nota que o corpo da função está vazio
}

void ShowWindow(const char* title, const wchar_t* text)
{
    Display* dpy = NULL;
    Window win;

    wchar_t** text_splitted;
    int textLines;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    split(text,L"\n" , &text_splitted, &textLines);
    ...
}
```

É algo muito estranho, pois a função está vazia. E quando não a chamo, o texto aparece com a cor preta, que é a normal.

[O código completo.](https://gist.github.com/Eleobert/d0a08875655b053a17e87f8c1c18f179)

Obs: As cores não aparecem quando **compilo** o código no Ubuntu, mas quando **compilo** no Debian aparecem.

Comment: Não é um problema do X11? Como você está imprimindo, na saída? Pode ser uma configuração do tipo TTY com ANSI

Comment: Não faço a mínima ideia se é ou não problema do X11. Olha só para isso https://pasteboard.co/HocpngM.png

Comment: Você comenta também o código para depurar o resultado? `for(i = 0; i < textLines; i++) { wprintf(L"%ls\n", text_splitted[i]); } fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: Sim. Só esqueci de adicionar no gist também.

Comment: Esses terminais com capacidade gráfica suportam caracteres de escape para cores, posicionamento em tela, caracteres cintilantes (piscantes)... Pode ser que, em algum momento do código, está a sair algum caractere desses.

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema. Eu estava declarando as variáveis no meio da função `ShowWindow`. Em `c` as variáveis devem ser declaradas no início de um bloco de código. (pelo menos acho que era isso)

Comment: seu problema não é passar as variáveis sem inicializar e não onde elas foram declaradas?

Comment: Não é isso. Até porque o corpo da função está vazio.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na na variável gcValues. Na linha 84, antes de chamar a função XCreateGC, deveria inicializar a variável membro foreground. O correto seria assim:

```
gcValues.font = XLoadFont(dpy, "7x13");
gcValues.foreground = BlackPixel(dpy, 0);
gc = XCreateGC(dpy, win, GCFont + GCForeground, &gcValues);
```